# I've created a code to convert binary to decimal, but doesn't work with more than 10 bits

Tags: c, binary, converters

I've created a small code to convert binary number to decimal number.
When I enter a binary number until 10 bits, the result be correct, but when I increase than 10 bits, the result would be wrong.

**The algorithm** that I used is the following

```
1   1   0  0  1  0
32  16  8  4  2  1 x
------------------
32+ 16+ 0+ 0+ 2+ 0
```

---

**The Code:**

```
unsigned long binary, i=0, j=0, result=0, base=1;
unsigned char *binaryStandalone = (unsigned char *)malloc(16);
memset(binaryStandalone, 0, 16);

printf("Enter a binary number: ");
scanf("%u", &binary);


while(binary > 0){
   binaryStandalone[i] = binary % 10;
   binary = binary / 10;
   i++;
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++){
   result +=  (binaryStandalone[j] * 1 << j);
   printf("%u = %u\n", j, base << j);
}
printf("The decimal number is: %u\n", result);

free(binaryStandalone);
```

Now I want to know, **what is the reason that the code doesn't give me the correct result when increase the binary number more than 10 bits ?**

Comment: You're using a native `unsigned long` (which on your platform appears to be 32-bits) as your binary number, which is actually a decimal integral. How many decimal "digits" are there in 0xFFFFFFFF ? Hint: the decimal value is 4294967295.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your platform uses 32 bit for a `long int`, therefore your `binary`
variable can hold at most the value `2^32 - 1 = 4294967295`, which is sufficient
for 10 digits, but not for eleven.

You could use `unsigned long long` instead (64 bit would be sufficient for 20 digits), or read the input as a string.

Comment: +1 For string input, consider a fixed-length buffer (say 256 chars) and a `scanf`  with something like: `scanf("%255['0','1']s", buffer);` as one possible way. You still need to translate all those digit *chars* to `0` and `1`, but at least it gets you closer.

Comment: ... or `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` and validate the input as you parse it.

Comment: ... and `scanf("%u", &binary);` is UB.

Answer (score 2):

you store in an unsigned long which has range 0 to 4,294,967,295 -> only 10 numbers

Answer (score 1):

Because the long value you're using to store the "binary" value has not more decimal digits. You might want to use a string type for input instead.